# Prove that $g$ is increasing if $f$ is differentiable on (0,1) and continuous on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Question**: Let $f$ be differentiable on (0,1) and continuous on [0,1]. Suppose that
$f(0) = $ and that $f′$ is increasing on (0,1). Let $g(x) =
f(x)/x$ for $x ∈ (0,1)$. Prove that $g$ is increasing on (0,1)

--

My answer regarding the said problem is:

Since $g$ is differentiable on (0,1), we need to show that $g'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x ∈ (0,1)$.

Let $x > 0$ be arbitrary. Suppose $f$ is differentiable on (0,1) and continuous at [0,1]. By the mean value theorem, there exists $c ∈ (0,x)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ = $\frac{f(x)}{x}$, or $f(x) = f'(c)x$

Since $0 < c < x$ , then $f'(c) < f'(x)$. Hence, the implication $\frac{f(x)}{x} < f'(x)$ implies that $f(x) < xf'(x)$. Also, by the quotient rule, $g'(x)=\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x^2}$. If we substitute the value $f'(c)x$ for $f(x)$ into the equation, it will give us

$g'(x) =\frac{xf'(x)-f'(c)x}{x^2}=\frac{f'(x)-f'(c)}{x}$

Therefore, $g'(x)>0$ for all $x > 0$ which concludes that $g$ is monotonically increasing.

--
Is my answer incorrect? or there are points that I should discuss in my answer? I hope someone would educate me on where I went wrong or if my answer is indeed correct.